# Local HTML + JS application with filesystem access

Tags: javascript, filesystem-access

I need to create an offline application with HTML and JS, that can edit and write files (local application folder, but NOT sandboxed browser local storage).

Is there any way to do this, in a reasonably lightweight and straightforward way? Researching this question gave me the following overview of available options - Electron is gigantic, Chrome Apps are a discontinued project, W3C FileSystem API was abandoned, W3C File API is very restrictive.

Comment: You cannot write to a local folder from the browser, you'll need a back end server. I'd use NodeJS since it's quite easy to learn if you already know Javascript

Comment: Another way to do is send and receive command to PHP or Node script

Comment: We are doing [Neutralinojs](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs) which solves this issue. But it is not complete yet. We just started developing it as open source framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been multiple attempts to create an SDK on top of Node.js for building desktop applications powered by modern HTML5 / CSS / JS frontends. [**AppJS**](http://appjs.com/) and its offshoot [**Deskshell**](https://github.com/sihorton/appjs-deskshell/) come to mind. And then there's [**Node-Qt**](https://github.com/arturadib/node-qt), which is built on top of the [**Qt platform**](https://www.qt.io/).

Unfortunately, none of these projects reached sufficient levels of maturity for me to recommend them, and they all seem to have been abandoned years ago. [**NW.js**](https://nwjs.io/) is the only alternative to Electron that I can think of that, at the moment, reached a decent level of maturity and is still being maintained.

That is, at least, if your focus is a desktop computer. For applications intended to be run on mobile devices, you might want to take a look at [**NativeScript**](https://www.nativescript.org/), [**React Native**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) or [**Tabris**](https://tabrisjs.com/).